# Python argparse how to add related group of options that are optional

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to add a group of options related to each other to existing script that has optional arguments and positional arguments to chose command to run.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='test')

parser.add_argument("-opt1", default="A", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-opt2", default="B", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-opt3", default="C", type=str)

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
cmd1 = subparsers.add_parser("cmd1", help="run cmd1")
cmd1.add_argument("-cmd1-opt1", default="cmd1-A")
cmd1.add_argument("-cmd1-opt2", default="cmd1-B")


cmd2 = subparsers.add_parser("cmd2", help="run cmd2")
cmd2.add_argument("-cmd2-opt", type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
```

For example I would like to add group of new optional options `opt4, opt5, opt6, opt7` which are related.
Something like `opt5` is valid option only when `opt4` has some value.

I could add all the options individually as optional arguments but I'm looking for any better way to do that being the options I want to add are related to each other.

Comment: You could try argument groups https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argument-groups which might improve readability for the help menu but I don't think there's a way to give such complex rules to argparse

Comment: `argparse` has 3 mechanisms for 'related' values, `nargs`, `mutually_exclusive_group` and `subparsers`.  Any further testing is best done after parsing.

Comment: You could add '--opt4' etc after the '--opt3', assuming you want them in the main parser.  Use `argument_group` if you want their help lines to display as a group.  But to do any co-occurrence testing, you'll have to do that after parsing.  `args.opt4 is not None` is a good test that `opt4` has a value.